# Using AngularJS Promise

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am currently attempting to learn the AngularJS framework and I keep hearing about something called "promise". I have researched a little about it, although I cannot seem to find a thorough explanation to how and when to use "promises".

Can anyone please explain and provide a solution between using a promise, and not using a promise. What is the advantage of using a promise over not using one?

All answer are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

promises implementation basically provides an interface which define at least one method 'when' that return therefore, a "Promise", thus a result from an async operation.

Advantages are better code readability (and production as well), better reuse of the results without incurring on the scaring "callbacks hell", chainabilty, etc...

A simple scenario with jQuery:

> without promises

```
$.ajax({
    url: someurl,
    success: function(data)
    {
        //do something with data
    }
});
```

> with promises

```
var p = $.ajax({ url: someurl });

$.when(p).then(function(data)
{
    //do something with data    
});
```

However, a better explanation: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A

Comment: So it is a more structured approach for handling data, errors, etc? Because as you have mentioned callback hell is not fun.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. In my opinion it's just an elegant hacky way to deal with data for languages which suffer from this "problem".

Comment: Also a simple implementation: http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2014/02/16/a-simple-promise-implementation-in-about-20-lines-of-javascript/

Comment: That is a nice article you have provided. It definitely makes a lot more sense now that you have explained it.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation says that

> The promise api allows for composition that is very hard
>   to do with the traditional callback (CPS ) approach. For more on this
>   please see the Q documentation  especially the section on serial or
>   parallel joining of promises.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

I think the easiest explanation could be that it's a much better and cleaner way to do a serial or very complex callbacks than the traditional way.

This is the link you can read more about the benefit of using promise:

[promises specification](https://github.com/kriskowal/uncommonjs/blob/master/promises/specification.md)